# Show that any group of order 294 is solvable.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

Show that any group of order 294 is solvable.

Proof: Suppose $G$ is a group of order $294=2\cdot 3\cdot 7^2$. By Sylow's Theorem,

- $n_2\equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $n_2|147$ $\Rightarrow$ $n_2=1,3,7,21,49,147$.
- $n_3\equiv 1 \mod 3$ and $n_3|98$  $\Rightarrow$ $n_3=1,7$.
- $n_7\equiv 1 \mod 7$ and $n_7|6$   $\Rightarrow$ $n_7=1$.

Hence there is a normal Sylow $7$-subgroup, $H$, with order $49$.

So where am I suppose to go from here?

Comment: Look at the definition of "solvable". See if you can make the existence of $H$ fit into that someplace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal Sylow $7$-subgroup $H$, being a $p$-group, is solvable. The quotient $G/H$ has order $6$ and is thus solvable (the first non-solvable group has order $60$). Hence $G$ is solvable.

Comment: How do you know $G/H$ is solvable?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Any group of order $6$ is isomorphic to $S_3$ or $C_6$, both of which are solvable.