# Show that every group of order $4125=3\cdot 5^3\cdot 11$ is solvable.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

Show that every group of order $4125=3\cdot 5^3\cdot 11$ is solvable.

Proof: Suppose $G$ is a group of order $4125$. By Sylow's Theorems,

- $n_3   \equiv 1 \mod 3$  and $n_3    | 5^3\cdot 11$   $\Rightarrow$ $n_3    = 1,25$.
- $n_5   \equiv 1 \mod 5$  and $n_5    | 33$            $\Rightarrow$ $n_5    = 1,11$.
- $n_{11}\equiv 1 \mod 11$ and $n_{11} | 5^3\cdot 3$    $\Rightarrow$ $n_{11} = 1,375$.

Sadly none of my $n_p$ are only $1$. How would I go about this problem?

Comment: $n_5=11$ will force there to be a normal subgroup whose order is divisible by $5$ (a closer look suggests $15$) and index divisible by $11$. From there getting solubility should b easy.

Comment: There are several solutions in the web, e.g., see [here](https://gtx0.com/thread/proof-that-there-is-no-simple-group-of-order-4125). Also compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058717/show-that-any-group-of-order-294-is-solvable).

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking for a quick answer, every group of odd order is solvable.